# R shiny selectizeInput not working with updateSelectizeInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have the code shared below.
I have multiple tabs one of which has a selectizeInput that contains a list of 50,000 unique values.
Hence, as suggested here https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html I use it server side.
For some reasons, the page Dashboard 2 that contains the selectizeInput  element doesn't react. The field is empty no matter what I type in there.
My code is structured using different R files given my really big shiny app.
However, in order to replicate the problem, two files are all you need. The first file is called "***app.R***" and contains the following code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage( 
  title = "Title test", 
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard header"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(  
    includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
    
    sidebarMenu(
      
     menuItem('Retail1', tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("th"),
              menuItem('Dashboard2', tabName = 'retail_dashboard1')
              ),
      
      menuItem('Retail2', tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("th"),
               menuItem('Dashboard2', tabName = 'retail_dashboard2')
               )
      
    )
  ),
  
  
  
  dashboardBody( 
    
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard2",
              uiOutput("ui_retail_dashboard2")              )
      
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {    
  
  source("Page_retail_dash2.R", local=T) 
  shiny::updateSelectizeInput(session=session, inputId ='element_with_list_of_cities', choices = rownames(mtcars), server = TRUE )
  
  
}
cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The second file is called "***Page_retail_dash2.R***" and contains the following simple code:

```
output$ui_retail_dashboard3 <- renderUI({ 
  
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Dashboard 3",

                       
                       h3("Test"),
                       fluidRow(
                         column(2,
                                selectizeInput(inputId = "element_with_list_of_cities_dash3",
                                               label = "Cities",
                                               choices = NULL, 
                                               selected = NULL,
                                               multiple = TRUE # allow for multiple inputs
                                               ,options = list(create = FALSE, maxOptions = 1000)  # if TRUE, allows newly created inputs))
                                )) 
                       )
              )
  )
})
```

If you simply copy and paste my code, you should be able to replicate the issue. I also attach here what I see my I run my app.[image]
You may ask why the first tab is empty. In my app it's not empty, it has some tables but you don't need it in order to replicate this issue.

Comment: For me it is not clear. Could you please clarify with more details.

Comment: Sure, the box that is supposed to show the list of values with the autocomplete is simply empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are updating too soon.  Your variable is `NULL` until you go to that tab, and only then you should update.  Define a `ID` in the `sidebarMenu`, and then `updateSelectizeInput` when you are in that specific tab.  Full code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage( 
  title = "Title test", 
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard header"),
  
  dashboardSidebar(  
    #includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
    
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
      
      menuItem('Retail1', tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("th"),
               menuItem('Dashboard1', tabName = 'retail_dashboard1')
      ),
      
      menuItem('Retail2', tabName = "tab2", icon = icon("th"),
               menuItem('Dashboard2', tabName = 'retail_dashboard2')
      )
      
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    
    tabItems(
      
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard2",
              uiOutput("ui_retail_dashboard2")              )
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {    
  
  source("Page_retail_dash2.R", local=T)
  # observe({
  #   print(input$element_with_list_of_cities) 
  #   print(input$tabs)
  # })
  observeEvent(input$tabs,{
    if (input$tabs=="retail_dashboard2")  updateSelectizeInput(session=session, inputId ='element_with_list_of_cities', 
                         choices = rownames(mtcars) , selected=rownames(mtcars)[1], server = TRUE )
  })
  
}
#cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Please not that your IDs should match and I have put a dummy selection in `Page_retail_dash2.R`

```
output$ui_retail_dashboard2 <- renderUI({ 
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("My Dashboard",
                       h3("Test"),
                       fluidRow(
                         column(2,
                                selectizeInput(inputId = "element_with_list_of_cities",
                                               label = "Cities",
                                               choices = c("A","B"), 
                                               selected = "A",
                                               multiple = TRUE # allow for multiple inputs
                                               ,options = list(create = FALSE, maxOptions = 10000L)  # if TRUE, allows newly created inputs))
                                )) 
                       )
              )
  )
})
```

Comment: you seriously made my day! if you'll ever be in NY let me know, drinks on me!

Comment: Depending on your use case you may want to consider using `updateTabItems`.

Comment: I live in midtown east, ping me whenever you're around!

Comment: Sure, will do.  Digging from sleet this morning...

Answer (score 1):

1. The `tabItems` call was missing.
2. To display more than 1000 choices we need to set something like: `selectizeInput(inputId = "myId", label = "myLabel", options = list(maxOptions = 100000L))`

---

Also check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70621460/9841389).

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage( 
  title = "Dashboard", 
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(   
    # includeCSS("www/styles.css"),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem('Retail', tabName = "dash1", icon = icon("th"),
               menuItem('Dashboard2', tabName = 'retail_dashboard2'),
               menuItem('Dashboard3', tabName = 'retail_dashboard3'),
               menuItem('Dashboard4', tabName = 'retail_dashboard4'),
               menuItem('Dashboard5', tabName = 'retail_dashboard5'),
               menuItem('Dashboard6', tabName = 'retail_dashboard6'),
               menuItem('Dashboard7', tabName = 'retail_dashboard7'),
               menuItem('Dashboard8', tabName = 'retail_dashboard8'),
               menuItem('Dashboard9', tabName = 'retail_dashboard9'),
               menuItem('Dashboard10', tabName = 'retail_dashboard10'),
               menuItem('Dashboard11', tabName = 'retail_dashboard11'),
               menuItem('Dashboard12', tabName = 'retail_dashboard12')
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody( 
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard3",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard3_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard4",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard4_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard5",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard5_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard6",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard6_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard7",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard7_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard8",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard8_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard9",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard9_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard10",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard10_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard11",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard11_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard12",
              h3('Text'),
              fluidRow(column(12,
                              dataTableOutput("retail_dashboard12_table")))
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "retail_dashboard2",
              h3("Test"),
              fluidRow(
                column(2,
                       selectizeInput(inputId = "element_with_list_of_cities",
                                      label = "Cities",
                                      choices = NULL, 
                                      selected = NULL,
                                      multiple = TRUE, # allow for multiple inputs
                                      options = list(create = FALSE, maxOptions = 100000L)  # if TRUE, allows newly created inputs))
                       )) 
              )            
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {    
  output$retail_dashboard3_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard4_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard5_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard6_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard7_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard8_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard9_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard10_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard11_table <- 
    output$retail_dashboard12_table <- renderDataTable({return(mtcars)})
  updateSelectizeInput(session=session, inputId ='element_with_list_of_cities', choices = 1:60000, server = TRUE)
}

cat("\nLaunching   'shinyApp' ....")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: That's a fair point but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I will also attach a screenshot of what I see. I see basically exactly what you shared in your screenshot, but no drop-down box shows up on my end.

Comment: @Angelo - than your example code does not reflect the problem. Please try to create a reproducible example.

Comment: @Angelo maybe the problem is, that the choices aren't loaded yet when you are trying to access them?

Comment: But how come though? As you can see I'm testing the code not with the actual vector (that has 50k + unique values) but simply with rownames(mtcars), so I can't really understand what may cause this problem

Comment: @Angelo have you set appropriate `options = list(create = FALSE, maxOptions = 100000L)` to allow so many choices in your `selectizeInput`? Please see my edit

Comment: Eventually I probably will, but now I can't even manage to display 4 different values!

Comment: Please copy and paste my example. It needs some time to load but it's fully working with 60000 choices.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to the code you shared here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70618250/how-to-add-a-spinner-before-a-selectizeinput-has-loaded-all-the-choices-shiny/70621460#70621460

Comment: @Angelo - No, I'm referring to my answer given above (see the new screenshot) - that link was just to provide you with some further information.

Comment: I actually have a better way for you to (hopefully) replicate the bug. It seems to be due to the fact I use multiple files. Let me edit the description of the bug above and perhaps you'll have a suggestion !

Comment: if you create the two files I mentioned and copy and paste the code, you should be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Angelo - after your edit the issue is clear. The problem is using `renderUI`. It is executed only after you first visited the tab. At this point `updateSelectizeInput` already tried to update the not yet existing `selectizeInput`. I won't update my answer again (it is working as it stands) because @YBS already provided a workaround regarding `renderUI`. See [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3348#issuecomment-810727477) for another workaround.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! The solution provided above by YBS has fixed the problem. Appreciated all your support.